# Unable to authorize GAS script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a published Web App Google App Script that has worked fine for several months, but just broke. I tried to share the app with a colleague so they could run it from their machines and not only could I not get it to work for them, but now it stops working for me.

In Publish\Deploy as a Web App, I have it set to Execute as Me and Anyone has access to the app. Underneath the box to execute as me, it says: "You need to authorize the script before distributing the URL."

After publishing the app, I have deauthorized and reauthorized the app. I have run the doGet(e) function and accepted the authorization.  However, when ever I try to invoke the app from the dev or exec url, the console gives me the following error: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (OK)
Uncaught NetworkError: Form submission failed.

I have not changed any code in the script. What other info can I provide to help diagnose? What else should I try?

I made a copy of the app and have the same issues.

**UPDATE:** It looks like this issue has been reported to Google (http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5189)

Comment: If the app has stop working without any changes, file an issue.  [Google Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: Are you using the DocList Service in that script? It might help us see if the problem is isolated or reproducible if you post your code.

Comment: I am not using DocsList but am using DriveApp. The error seems to concatenate a nocache variable and  a token. I remplaced my sheet ID and function names for clarity: https://script.google.com/a/macros/wsj.com/s/[MY_SHEET_ID]&func=[MYFUNCTION]&token=AJuLMu3RUV4U_qT58PyRVMd4ptXS9EuoUQ%3A1435695753768 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (OK)

Answer (score 0):

The referred issue was reported as fixed. Ref. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763604